# How to sned the NEC IR Code in ConsumerIrManager.transmit()

Tags: android

I used the ConsumerIrManager class in Android 4.4.2 and my Samsung S5.

```
mCIR = (ConsumerIrManager) getSystemService(CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);
Log.e(DBTAG,"mCIR.hasIrEmitter(): " + mCIR.hasIrEmitter());
if (!mCIR.hasIrEmitter()) {
    Log.e(DBTAG, "No IR Emitter found\n");
}
else{
    pm = getPackageManager();
    Log.e(DBTAG,"pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CONSUMER_IR): " + pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CONSUMER_IR)); 
}`enter code here`
```

This is my part of code and I can turn on the Irda LED.
But I dont know how to send the NEC IR code via `mCIR.transmit( 38000, p1);`
and I try to

```
int[] p1={0x83,0xF4,0x17,0xE8};
mCIR.transmit( 38000, p1);
```

But it seems wrong so does any one can help me about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "pattern" parameter of the "transmit" method is not actually the code you want to send. The values you put in are the number of cycles for "ON" and "OFF" states starting with "ON".

Example:

Assume you have a 38kHz frequency and want to send an "ON" pulse for 0.5 seconds followed by an "OFF" space for 0.25 seconds followed by an "ON" pulse for 0.5 seconds. Your pattern array will need to be:

```
int[] pattern = {(int)(38000*0.5), (int)(38000*0.25), (int)(38000*0.5)};
```

Also the signal is not automatically sent in NEC encoding, you have to come up with the algorithm for the [NEC protocol](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/FPGA/NEC+Infrared+Transmission+Protocol).

Answer (score 2):

```
    private static int[] NEcToImpulses(string nec)
    {
        // NEC "44BB3BC4".
        //Convert to bits.
        //0100 0100 1011 1011 0011 10111100 0100
        string bites = string.Join(string.Empty, nec.Select(c => Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString(), 16), 2).PadLeft(4, '0')));

        List<int> impulses = new List<int>();
        //Start of package
        impulses.Add(9000);
        impulses.Add(4500);

        foreach (var item in bites)
        {
            impulses.Add(562);
            if (item == '0')
            {
                impulses.Add(562);
            }
            else
            {
                impulses.Add(1688);
            }
        }
        // End of packet pulse
        impulses.Add(562);

        return impulses.ToArray() ;
    }
```

And we call with frequency 38222.

```
string nec = "44BB3BC4";
consumerIrManager.Transmit(38222, NEcToImpulses(nec));
```